# Efficient way of reading large txt file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to open a txt file with 4605227 rows (305 MB)

The way I have done this before is:

```
data = np.loadtxt('file.txt', delimiter='\t', dtype=str, skiprows=1)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"])

df = df.astype(dtype={"a": "int64", "h": "int64", "i": "int64"})
```

But it's using up most of available ram ~10GB and not finishing.
Is there a faster way of reading in this txt file and creating a pandas dataframe?

Thanks!

Edit:
Solved now, thank you. Why is np.loadtxtx() so slow?

Comment: what happen with `df = pd.read_csv9('file.txt', delimiter='\t', dtype=str, skiprows=1)`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas, 6gb file in the tag question

Comment: agreed with @QuangHoang 305 MB should be readable with pandas directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than reading it in with numpy you could just read it directly in as a Pandas DataFrame. E.g., using the [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) function, with something like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', delimiter='\t', usecols=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"])
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise read_csv allowed for tab delimited. However I get this error: TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'

Comment: Because the parameter is not called `columns` but `usecols` (as in the docs Matt linked)

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 :

You can read the file by chunks , Moreover there is a buffer size which ou can mention in readline and you can read.

```
inputFile = open('inputTextFile','r')
buffer_line = inputFile.readlines(BUFFERSIZE)
while buffer_line:
    #logic goes here
```

Method 2:

You can also use nmap Module , Here below is the link whic will explain the usage.

import mmap

```
with open("hello.txt", "r+b") as f:
    # memory-map the file, size 0 means whole file
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    # read content via standard file methods
    print(mm.readline())  # prints b"Hello Python!\n"
    # read content via slice notation
    print(mm[:5])  # prints b"Hello"
    # update content using slice notation;
    # note that new content must have same size
    mm[6:] = b" world!\n"
    # ... and read again using standard file methods
    mm.seek(0)
    print(mm.readline())  # prints b"Hello  world!\n"
    # close the map
    mm.close()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html

Answer (score 0):

You read it directly in as a Pandas DataFrame. eg

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv(path)
```

If you want to read faster, you can use modin:

```
import modin.pandas as pd
pd.read_csv(path)
```

https://github.com/modin-project/modin